# Enforce template to be a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

How do I ensure that a given template parameter is a protocol?

A `GKEntity` has a function called `component(ofType: class)` and i want to add `component(ofProtocol: Protocol)`. It does look like this:

```
extension GKEntity {
    func component<T: Protocol>(ofProtocol: T) -> T? {
        return self.components.first() { component in
            return component.conforms(to: ofProtocol)
        } as? T
    }
}
```

I want to use it in an component which holds a reference to the entity like this:

```
let component = self.entity?.component(ofProtocol: SpriteComponentProtocol)
```

but somehow i always get:

Showing All Messages

```
Cannot convert value of type 'SpriteComponentProtocol.Protocol' to expected argument type 'Protocol'
```

---

Update:

The idea is that i have a component for a Sprite:

```
protocol SpriteComponentProtocol {
    var spriteNode: SKSpriteNode { get set }
}

class SpriteComponent: GKComponent {
    var spriteNode: SKSpriteNode?
}
```

And a other component for the control:

```
protocol PlayerControlComponentProtocol {
    var steerAngle: Double { get set }
}

class PlayerControlComponent: GKComponent, PlayerControlComponentProtocol {
    var steerAngle: Double = 90.0

    override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        //here i do manipulate the spriteComponent.spriteNode
        let comp = self.entity?.component(ofProtocol: SpriteComponentProtocol)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to exchange the SpriteComponent at any time.

Comment: So brings us to something like this: `self.entity?.component(ofProtocol: SpriteComponentProtocol.self) as? SpriteComponentProtocol` if i return a `GKComponent` instead of the template T and add the objc reference to the protocol

Comment: This requires the objc export right? The idea is, that i do not have a requirement to a fixed class. Instead i want it to be a protocol so i can easily exchange it to something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `Protocol` is an opaque type that describes an Obj-C protocol, so if you want to bridge `SpriteComponentProtocol.self` over to it, you need to mark `SpriteComponentProtocol` as `@objc` (but even if you did; you wouldn't be able to cast to `T`, because the returned instance isn't of type `Protocol`).

But that being said, you don't need to use the Obj-C `Protocol` type or `conforms(to:)` method here, you can simply use the conditional type-casting operator `as?` in an overload of `component(ofType:)` *without* the `GKComponent` constraint on `T`:

```
extension GKEntity {

    func component<T>(ofType type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return self.components.lazy.flatMap{ $0 as? T }.first
    }
}
```

We're using `lazy` here in order to avoid evaluating all the `components`, and then `flatMap(_:)` and `first` in order to get the first element that's castable to `T` (and in the case of `T` being a protocol type, this gives us the first element that conforms to the protocol).

You can then simply use it like so:

```
protocol SpriteComponentProtocol {
    var spriteNode: SKSpriteNode { get set }
}

class PlayerControlComponent: GKComponent {

    override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        let comp = self.entity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponentProtocol.self)
    }
}
```

And in Swift 4, you can remove this overload entirely, and instead simply call `GKEntity`'s [`component(ofType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkentity/2300466-component) method with a class existential metatype:

```
let comp = self.entity?.component(ofType: (GKComponent & SpriteComponentProtocol).self)
```

As now `T` satisfies the `: GKComponent` constraint. You can then access both `GKComponent` methods and `SpriteComponentProtocol` protocol requirements on the unwrapped instance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is a good way to make sure that I cant mess it up later even though that I have tests for this.

Comment: Can we default the bridge to be the `{%0}` closure?

Comment: That does make sense. Unfortunately i am not that much into the generic traits of swift. I think writing tests for that and having a different method signature then the `component(ofType…)` should be all right to make sure nobody tries to add a new component which is not conform for the other components.

Comment: Awesome. The compiler doesn't complain if i pass in the Protocol without @objc. Are you sure that i now have to do this?

Comment: @BennX Correct, `@objc` is no longer required :)